# How can verify an NFT that I want to act as an access card?

Tags: blockchain, nft

Hey guys I'm trying to create a social group that has real world and cyber space meet ups.

I wanted the group to each have an edition of a NFT that I create and they get. When at these events how could I verify on the spot that they own the NFT? Would I have them pull up there NFT on there phone and check for something that would be unique? Or is there a process in which I could scan or quickly look up that the NFT belongs to the person?

I see some other sites based around NFT say that it gives you access to their private discord channel. How could I make my NFT have that same capability? Or am I looking at it wrong. Basically when the NFT are distributed I want to know exactly who owns the NFT so that they can get the benefits and I want to know if there is a way they can use there NFT to access a private discord channel that others cant?

I'm very new to this and I am not sure if I am even asking the right questions. So I hope I find some direction.

Comment: Check the Poap project.

Answer (score 0):

The only real way to verify if they own a NFT is to check if they own the public address that owns that NFT (the latter you can check on etherscan).

And to prove they own a certain public address they would have to sign a message (once, and this will cost a gas fee) verifying that they indeed own that address.

For example a very easy way to sign a message is make a tx to yourself of 0ETH. You can even include a HEX message with the tx by using the HEX data functionality of metamask, but this isn't really necessary if you just give them a time window for the 0ETH tx.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do what's known as a 'proof of possession' transaction to determine if the user has the private-key matching the wallet address (aka public-key). This is typically done by offering up a nonce and having the user sign the nonce (or any degenerate transaction). Since this is entirely off-chain there is no cost to anyone. That said:
1 you need to develop the 'web app' that will prompt the user to sign and then verify the signature
2 the user needs to have their private-key (ie wallet) on them at the time of proof (ie at a movie theater entrance)
3 the user needs to have enough faith in the world to sign the transaction

Once you have done a key POP on the user you can then lookup that wallet to see if it owns the NFT in question, or lookup the NFT and see if that wallet owns the NFT in question.

If yes to both allow them in.
Good luck with that :)

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you're looking for may call `NFT membership`. You can check out the [Unlock protocol](https://unlock-protocol.com/) to read more about it